# Cannot add weight param to fragment in android studio?

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to add weight param to fragment xml in android studio so that my two fragements can take half screen each but adding weight have no effect on the layout. what interesting is i still can add weight to normal activity views here is the [screen shot](https://gyazo.com/c923358336b863cb2d0dc247b3aa8fbb)

Here is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="io.designcoder.vivz.lifecycle.xml.ActivityFragmentXml">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_xml_a"
    class="io.designcoder.vivz.lifecycle.xml.FragmentXmlA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_xml_a"
    />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_xml_b"
    class="io.designcoder.vivz.lifecycle.xml.FragmentXmlB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_xml_a"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_xml_b"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your fragment in LinearLayout. and make your fragment width 0dp

Comment: Is your fragment inside LinearLayout or RelativeLayout ?

Comment: Please share your layout file.

Comment: weights only work in **LinearLayouts**. You are using a RelativeLayout, instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remember that: weight param can only work in linearlayout. if you want to let the two fragments share the screen in horizontal, make the orientation of linearlayout horizontal and make the width of each fragment "0dp" or "wrap_content" so that you can weight them. The same way in vertical. You can look my codes below for example.
[the weight example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRXp7.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.dysaniazzz.testdemo.MainActivity">

   //the background only to distinguish the fragment
   <fragment
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
  <fragment
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please, provide the code snippets explicitly in the answer itself. The answer has to be more focused on the topic, instead of providing something generic.

Comment: thanks, @DysaniazzZ, this is much better, get the up-vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

You try using code below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="cungxunu.cunghoangdao.cheng.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <fragment
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Relative layout as weight would not work there.
So User Linear layout for that.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="io.designcoder.vivz.lifecycle.xml.ActivityFragmentXml">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_xml_a"
    class="io.designcoder.vivz.lifecycle.xml.FragmentXmlA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_xml_a"
    />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_xml_b"
    class="io.designcoder.vivz.lifecycle.xml.FragmentXmlB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_xml_a"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_xml_b"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```